# How to disable right mouse click in eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

When right mouse button clicking on a textbox,
the context menu would pop up as below.

[image: Example]

In Eclipse plugin, how do I disable the context menu with Java?

Comment: Is this a text control that you are creating?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just try to use setVisible(false) and setRemoveAllWhenShown(true) of MenuManager to disable it, but it does not work now.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting an empty menu on the control:

```java
Menu menu = new Menu(textControl);
textControl.setMenu(menu);
```

This works on Mac OS X, I am not sure if it will work on all platforms.